# Django 1.9 class-based view singleton

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-class-based-views

There is one problem with class-based views in Django that I can't find and easy solution.

Let's create some class-based view:

```
class userspaceDispatcher(View):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.someSharedStuff = MongoConnector() # As example

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Some code here, it does not matter
        return dispatchResult
```

Then, when we will make HTTP call, that will pass to my view, every time will be created new instance of userspaceDispatcher.
As example, to handle requests I need MongoDB connector. As I can see on the profiler, initialization of connector takes 5-7ms.

So the question is - how to make view class singleton? Not to be initialized every request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this kind of thing is the same with class based view as it is with function based ones. Define the shared value outside the view, at module level, so it will be instantiated only once per process.

Comment: May I ask you for the link to the example?

Comment: Solved with adding 

SHARED_DISPATCHERS = {}

Before class definition.